# Log4net log files not created?

Tags: c#, vsto, log4net

We are using log4net in our outlook add-in application, it was worked fine. We are used VSTO 2010 (its supports outlook 2007 and 2010).

> For some reason we updated the VSTO version in our system (its
>   supports outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013). After that log files are not
>   created in our system. Don't know what was problem.

Comment: Have you enabled internal debugging of log4net?

Comment: Yes it was enabled only.

Answer (score 4):

Finally i got the solution for my problem.

We need to specify the config file name while declaring log4net.

For example:

> [assembly: log4net.Config.DOMConfigurator(ConfigFile =
>   "[ProjectName].dll.config", Watch = true)]